# Meteor Mongo: Unset doesn't seem to work

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Meteor Mongo's unset doesn't seem to work for me. I run the following code and nothing happens. I'm trying to remove a field from an object that looks like: (where `kaldj12lasasd`, for example, is a group ID). Also if it helps I'm using `https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles` to help manage roles and groups.

I'm running this code from a collection hook when the group is removed from the Groups collection. I want to remove all the groupId fields from every user with that groupId as a field.

```
# User obj
user = {
  kaldj12lasasd: ['admin', 'read', 'write']
}

# Remove it from every users' role array
unsetObj = {};
unsetObj[group._id] = "";

Meteor.users.update({}, {$unset: unsetObj});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/) the roles are defined on a `roles` sub-field of user - not directly on the object. It seems like you'd want `unsetObj` to look like `{'roles.kaldj12lasasd: ''}`. Also, you appear to be missing `{multi: true}` so that the update affects more than one document. Try this:

```js
var unsetObj = {};
unsetObj['roles.' + group._id] = '';
Meteor.users.update({}, {$unset: unsetObj}, {multi: true});
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://atmospherejs.com/alanning/roles) the roles are defined on a `roles` sub-field of user - not directly on the object. It seems like you'd want `unsetObj` to look like `{'roles.kaldj12lasasd: ''}`.